# Can't generate keys for ADB

Tags: adb

I'm trying to use ADB on an ARM device running Ubuntu 18.

The Ubuntu machine communicates with the android phone and can access its files. However, listing the devices on ADB produces an error relating to generating the adbkeys in the .android directory.

Command:

```
adb devices -l
```

Error:

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.1000.log
Server had pid: 8409
--- adb starting (pid 8409) ---
adb I 02-04 01:26:21  8409  8409 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 02-04 01:26:21  8409  8409 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04
adb I 02-04 01:26:21  8409  8409 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 02-04 01:26:21  8409  8409 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 02-04 01:26:21  8409  8409 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 02-04 01:26:21  8409  8409 adb_auth_host.cpp:262] User key '/home/odroid/.android/adbkey' does not exist...
adb I 02-04 01:26:21  8409  8409 adb_auth_host.cpp:109] generate_key(/home/odroid/.android/adbkey)...

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Manually restarting the service with kill-service and start-service and using sudo yield the same result. The .android directory remains empty. ADB worked fine on a Windows 10 machine with the same android phone, so I copied the adbkey files from the Windows 10 machine to the Ubuntu machine in the hope of getting lucky (I don't know what they do). That produced a different error with the same command:

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.0.log
Server had pid: 8699
--- adb starting (pid 8699) ---
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/home/odroid/.android/adbkey'...
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 adb_auth_host.cpp:391] adb_auth_inotify_init...
adb I 02-04 01:31:38  8699  8699 adb_auth_host.cpp:467] Calling send_auth_response

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224078